# Is there anyway to use colspan on the do_settings_fields in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress options page, for creating fields I use the codes like this:

```
$sections['helper'] = array(
    'title' => '<span>' . __('Help', 'ngin') . '</span>',
    'menu_title' => __('Help', 'ngin'),
    'icon' => 'fa-help',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            // Field name: usually not used
            'type' => 'custom_html',
            // HTML content
            'std'  => '<div class="alert alert-warning">This is a custom HTML content.</div>',
            'desc' => __('This is custom HTML example.', 'ngin'), 
            // PHP function to show custom HTML
            // 'callback' => 'display_warning',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Later, I use `do_settings_sections($idx.'_section');` and this function uses `do_settings_fields` function here you see: [do_settings_sections( string $page )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_settings_sections/) like this:

```
echo '<table class="form-table">';
do_settings_fields( $page, $section['id'] );
echo '</table>';
```

Finally it generates the code like this:

```
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 1</th>
    <td>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">Content 1</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 2</th>
    <td>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">Content 2</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 3</th>
    <td>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">Content 3</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 4</th>
    <td>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">Content 4</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to use first Content div with full width and I do'nt want to see `<th scope="row">Header 1</th>`. But I do not know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using [Fluent Framework](https://github.com/HeadwayLabs/fluent). We can see this from using `custom_html`. This framework uses fields to create options pages, meta boxes, taxonomy meta etc. On the other hand, I don't think we can change the `scope = "row"` without interrupting WordPress Core and using JavaScript. Do not interfere with WordPress Core. This is definitely not recommended.

Now, crete a javascript file to `fields/custom_html` directory and hide `scope` with jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('th[scope="row"]').first().hide();
});
```

Enqueue the javascript file like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-html-js', PATH.'fields/custom_html/custom_html.js', array('jquery'), time(),  true);
```

This will hide the `scope = "row"` cell when the page is loaded. Of course you can use `jQuery.each` if you want to hide all `scope = "row"` cells.